# R, dplyr: Collapse character variable elements by group if there is only one unique non-NA element per group

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have the following data.frame `df` of patient hometowns and one arbitrary clinical metric, heart rate:

```
id          <- c(rep(1:3, each = 2), rep(4, 3))
pt_hometown <- c("Atlanta", NA, 
                 NA, "San Diego", 
                 NA, NA, 
                 "San Francisco", "Seattle", NA)
pt_heartrate <- c(NA, 82,
                  NA, NA,
                  76, 76,
                  90, 93, NA)

df <- data.frame(id = id, 
                 pt_hometown = pt_hometown,
                 pt_heartrate = pt_heartrate,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
```

Which gives

```
id   pt_hometown pt_heartrate
 1       Atlanta           NA
 1          <NA>           82
 2          <NA>           NA
 2     San Diego           NA
 3          <NA>           76
 3          <NA>           76
 4 San Francisco           90
 4       Seattle           93
 4          <NA>           NA
```

[As I've learned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509462/how-to-collapse-many-records-into-one-while-removing-na-values), `summarise_each` can apply one or more functions to a grouped dataframe to collapse records to one per group. The simplest case might be selecting the first non-NA value from all variables within `df` and collapsing them down to one per group.

```
  df1 <- df %>%  
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(first(.[!is.na(.)]))

df1

id   pt_hometown pt_heartrate
 1       Atlanta           82
 2     San Diego           NA
 3            NA           76
 4 San Francisco           90
```

Of course, for practical applications, one might want to collapse with a bit more specificity. I know how to group `df`'s variables by type and, for instance, select the `max` heart rate per `id` and collapse to one record, but **what I do not know how to do is conditionally collapse character variables to one record per group, given there is only one unique non-NA value**.

More concretely, consider the patient with `id` number 4. They have two unique values for `pt_hometown`, "San Francisco" and "Seattle". Obviously both cannot be correct. So **I would like to collapse records for each group where there is only one non-NA value, but retain rows where multiple non-NA elements exist** and then bring it to the attention of our group to decide how to correct the mistake in the original dataset.

So I'd like `df1` to look like this:

```
id   pt_hometown pt_heartrate
 1       Atlanta           82
 2     San Diego           NA
 3          <NA>           76
 4 San Francisco           90
 4       Seattle           93
```

This is what I've tried:

```
df1 <- df %>%  
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_each_(funs(first(.[!is.na(.)])), df[length(unique(.[!is.na(.)])) == 1])
```

Comment: To my knowledge, `summarise` and `summarise_each` currently only allow 1 row per group returned. The developers [are discussing](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/154) how to make it more flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented above, there is currently no way to use `dplyr::summarise_each` with variable number of rows to be returned.

If you want to go on using dplyr, you could circumvent this by using `mutate_each` and `distinct`.

Here's an example:

```
f <- function(.) if(length(unique(.[!is.na(.)])) > 1L) . else first(.[!is.na(.)]) 

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(f)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct() %>% 
  filter(rowSums(is.na(.)) < 2L)     # assuming you don't have NAs in the ID column

#Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
#
#  id   pt_hometown pt_heartrate
#1  1       Atlanta           82
#2  2     San Diego           NA
#3  3            NA           76
#4  4 San Francisco           90
#5  4       Seattle           93
```

However, the data.table approach in my answer to your previous question or that by eddi would probably be more efficient.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks again for sticking with these questions. It's on my list to branch out to `data.table` one of these days. Now if I could only find the time... :)

Comment: Another question -- say that instead of only 1 character variable in this data.frame `df` (`pt_hometown`), I had dozens, and I only wanted to select those variables instead of the whole `df`. I know I would use a `select` function at the end of the `%>%` chain. However, how can I pass a character vector containing the names of the character columns in `df` (named `dfcharvars`, for example) to `select`? I tried `select_(dfcharvars)` but it only selects the first element of that vector. Thanks.

Comment: Figured out a work around, but would still like to know how to use `select`... what I did was just use `%>% .[dfcharvars]` at the end. Which seems too simple...

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little unclear on what you want for some edge cases, but this works for the OP:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df) # or convert in place using setDT

unique(dt, by = c('id', 'pt_hometown'))[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = id]
#   id   pt_hometown pt_heartrate
#1:  1       Atlanta           82
#2:  2     San Diego           NA
#3:  3            NA           76
#4:  4 San Francisco           90
#5:  4       Seattle           93
```