# Using mutate over multiples columns with a for loop to recode values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I need to recode values over multiple columns of a data frame based on another table.

I have to recode the values of multiple columns of a data table using a side table.
The values correspond to geographic identifiers that I must replace with place names.
So I decided to do a loop but what works outside the loop doesn't work anymore .
I can't use mutate in for loop.

*My real data contains 274 columns with 38 columns to recode. This columns have many different names (they aren't call places")*

my main dataset :

```
 id <- c(1, 2, 3)
 departure <- c(1, 2, NA)
 arrival <- c(3, 1, 2)
 transit <- c(NA,NA,1)
dataset <- data.frame(id, departure, arrival, transit)
```

The other table :

```
geo_id <- c(1, 2, 3)
place_name <- c("Paris", "Nantes", "London")
geocode <- data.frame(geo_id, place_name)
```

My loop :

```
var <- c("departure", "arrival", "transit") #the columns that should by recode (must be a vector with my  real data)

for (i in var) {
  print(i)
  dataset <- dataset %>% 
  mutate(i = geocode$place_name[match(i, geocode$geo_id)])

}
```

mutate create a new column call `i` ! How to avoid this ?

Comment: Have you tried `mutate_at`? This looks like what it's designed for

Comment: @camille 1 not working !

Comment: Not working how?

Comment: @camille 1 Error in check_dot_cols(.vars, .cols) : 
  l'argument ".vars" est manquant, avec aucune valeur par défaut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
dataset %>%
 mutate_at(vars(one_of(var)), ~ geocode$place_name[match(., geocode$geo_id)])

  id place1 place2 place3
1  1  Paris London   <NA>
2  2 Nantes  Paris   <NA>
3  3   <NA> Nantes  Paris
```

Or with the addition of `tidyr`:

```
dataset %>%
 pivot_longer(one_of(var)) %>%
 left_join(geocode, by = c("value" = "geo_id")) %>%
 select(-value) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = place_name)
```

Comment: In my real dataset, variables don't begin by place. I have a vector with varables names...

Comment: Updated it accordingly :)

Comment: In my real dataset, I have 274 colmuns, colmuns to recode and other columns are not ordered.

Comment: It is applying it only on columns in your vector. Isn't this what you are interested in?

Comment: Then both possibilities should work. What is the issue?

Comment: I am testing on my real data .

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to join the datasets. You can use this `dplyr` function and drop any unneeded columns.

```
comb <- dplyr::left_join(dataset, geocode, by = (c("id" = "geo_id")))
comb

  id place1 place2 place3 place_name
1  1      1      3     NA      Paris
2  2      2      1     NA     Nantes
3  3     NA      2      1     London
```

Comment: I need to replace id values by names over 38 columns in reality

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do:

```
# select cols to recode
cols <- c('place1','place2')

# get other columns
other_cols <- setdiff(colnames(dataset), cols)

# recode df
recode_df = sapply(cols, function(x) place_name[dataset[[x]]])

# get all columns together
df = cbind(recode_df, dataset[other_cols])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are simpler ways but the code below works and if the `var` vector of variables to change is preprocessed as one regex pattern, this code seems to be general, not depending on the number or names of the columns.

Part of it is inspired in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28682198/8245406) to another question. The auxiliary function `f` is taken from there.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

var_pattern <- paste(var, collapse = "|")

f <- function(.) if(length(unique(.[!is.na(.)])) > 1L) . else first(.[!is.na(.)]) 

dataset %>%
  gather(place, value, -id) %>%
  mutate(place_name = geocode$place_name[value]) %>%
  spread(place, place_name) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches(var_pattern)), f) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct() %>% 
  filter(rowSums(is.na(.)) < 2L) 
## A tibble: 3 x 4
#     id place1 place2 place3
#  <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  <fct> 
#1     1 Paris  London NA    
#2     2 Nantes Paris  NA    
#3     3 NA     Nantes Paris
```