# R - Collapsing rows to closest date when NA

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's suppose I have this dataframe:

```
Date        A   B
2010-01-01  NA  1
2010-01-02  2   NA
2010-01-05  3   NA
2010-01-07  NA  4
2010-01-20  5   NA
2010-01-25  6   7
```

I want to collapse rows, removing the NA values to the closest Date. So the result would be:

```
Date        A  B
2010-01-02  2  1
2010-01-07  3  4
2010-01-20  5  NA
2010-01-25  6  7
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509462/how-to-collapse-many-records-into-one-while-removing-na-values) stack overflow that solves collapsing using a key value, but I could not find a similar case using close date values to collapse.

**Obs1**: It would be good if there was a way to not collapse the rows if the dates are too far apart (example: more than 15 days apart).

**Obs2**: It would be good if the collapsing lines kept the latter date rather than the earlier, as shown in the example above.

Comment: Do you expect to collapse more than 2 rows?

Comment: Only collapse where there is NA (so in the example above the answer would be no). If there were more columns it could be the case to collapse more than 2 rows.

Comment: Yea. I was thinking on similar line and in solution I tried to collapse until both `A` and `B` got `non-NA` values.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` package an option could be to `group_by` on combination of `A` and `B` in such a way that they form complete values.

Considering **`Obs#2`** the `max` of Date should be taken for combined row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
  mutate(GrpA = cumsum(!is.na(A)), GrpB = cumsum(!is.na(B))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Grp = max(GrpA, GrpB)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-GrpA, -GrpB) %>%
  group_by(Grp) %>%
  summarise(Date = max(Date), A = A[!is.na(A)][1], B = B[!is.na(B)][1])

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
# Grp Date           A     B
# <int> <date>     <int> <int>
# 1     1 2010-01-02     2     1
# 2     2 2010-01-07     3     4
# 3     3 2010-01-20     5    NA
# 4     4 2010-01-25     6     7
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Date        A   B
2010-01-01  NA  1
2010-01-02  2   NA
2010-01-05  3   NA
2010-01-07  NA  4
2010-01-20  5   NA
2010-01-25  6   7",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This does not work. For example, using the following df, the line where B = 5 disappears: df <- read.table(text = 
                   "Date        A   B
                 2010-01-01  NA  1
                 2010-01-02  2   NA
                 2010-01-05  3   NA
                 2010-01-06  8   NA
                 2010-01-07  NA  4
                 2010-01-08  NA  5
                 2010-01-20  5   NA",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

Comment: @Daniel That's true. Its not considering that case. Let me re-visit it.