# dplyr, R: Counting a specific value in multiple columns at once

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame:

```
md <- data.frame(a = c(3,5,4,5,3,5), b = c(5,5,5,4,4,1), c = c(1,3,4,3,5,5),
      device = c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
myvars = c("a", "b", "c")
md[2,3] <- NA
md[4,1] <- NA
md
```

I want to count number of 5s in each column - by device. I can do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(md, device) %>% 
summarise(counts.a = sum(a==5, na.rm = T),
          counts.b = sum(b==5, na.rm = T),
          counts.c = sum(c==5, na.rm = T))
```

However, in real life I'll have tons of variables (the length of `myvars` can be very large) - so that I can't specify those `counts.a`, `counts.b`, etc. manually - dozens of times.

Does `dplyr` allow to run the count of 5s on all `myvars` columns at once?

Thank you!

Comment: See `?summarise_each` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644848/summarizing-multiple-columns-with-dplyr?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the names there, but this works: `md %>% group_by(device) %>% summarise_each(funs(counts=sum(.==5,na.rm=TRUE)))`

Comment: @Frank May be `md %>% group_by(device) %>% select_(.dots=myvars) %>% summarise_each(funs(counts=sum(.==5,na.rm=TRUE)))` or just `md %>% group_by(device) %>% summarise_each_(funs(counts=sum(.==5, na.rm=TRUE)), myvars)`

Comment: @akrun Still no names in the result when I run either of those (R 3.2.0, dplyr 0.4.1). Seems that `summarise_each` just ignores names inside `funs`...

Comment: @Frank Have you tried with `summarise_each_`

Comment: @akrun Yes, I tried the second version in your comment, but still see `a` `b` `c` as the columns, with `counts` appearing nowhere.

Comment: @Frank Never mind, I thought something different.  I guess you are talking about `count.a`, `count.b` etc in the names, right

Answer (score 3):

If you care about the names starting with "counts." you could do it like this in a dplyr pipe:

```
md %>% 
  group_by(device) %>% 
  summarise_each_(funs(sum(.==5,na.rm=TRUE)), myvars) %>% 
  setNames(c(names(.)[1], paste0("counts.", myvars)))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
#
#  device counts.a counts.b counts.c
#1      1        1        2        0
#2      2        0        1        0
#3      3        1        0        2
```

There's another Q&A about how one can name new columns produced by dplyr's `mutate_each` (which behaves the same way as `summarise_each`) here: [mutate_each in dplyr: how do I select certain columns and give new names to mutated columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027347).

Answer (score 2):

The `melt()` function from the `reshape2` package could be useful in this case. You might want to try this:

```
 library(reshape2)
 mydf <- melt(md,id="device")
 thefives <- mydf[which(mydf$value==5),]
 print(table(thefives))
```

Here's the output:

```
, , value = 5

     variable
device a b c
     1 1 2 0
     2 0 1 0
     3 1 0 2
```

If required, the `table` format obtained  from this output can be converted into a `data.frame` by first converting it into a `matrix`:

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(matrix(table(thefives),nrow=3))
colnames(mydf) <- c("a","b","c")
rownames(mydf) <-paste0("device_",c(1:3))
print(mydf)
```

This yields the following result:

```
         a b c
device_1 1 2 0
device_2 0 1 0
device_3 1 0 2

> class(mydf)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: Thank you. I know how to do it in Base R and reshape2 is a good idea too. But I want to know if it's possible to do it in dplyr.

Comment: Besides, the structure of the output is of table() is inconvenient. I need a data frame at the end.