# Selecting specific columns when using mutate_each function from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame with the first column as a categorical identifier, the second column as a frequency value and the remaining columns as raw data counts. I want to multiply all the count columns by the frequency column but not the first two.

All the raw count columns start with a capital letter followed by a full stop, e.g "L.abd", T.xyz etc.

For example, if I use the code:

```
    require(dplyr)
    ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    Freq <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.3)
    L.abc <- c(1,1,1,3,1,0)
    L.ABC <- c(0,3,2,4,1,1)
    T.xyz <- c(1,1,1,1,0,1)
    F.ABC <- c(4,5,6,5,3,1)

    df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, Freq, L.abc, L.ABC, T.xyz, F.ABC))

    df_new <- df %>% mutate_each(funs(.*Freq), starts_with("L."))
```

I can create a new data frame containing the categorical data columns along with those columns starting with "L." which have been multiplied by the corresponding frequency value.

Is there a way to change the "starts_with" command to select all columns that begin with a capital letter and a full stop? My attempts to date using modifications such as "[A-Z]." have been unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For these cases, `matches` would be more appropriate

```
  df %>%
      mutate_each(funs(.*Freq), matches("^[A-Z]\\.", ignore.case=FALSE))
```

Here, I am assuming that you wanted to `select` only column names that start with a capital letter (`^[A-Z]`) followed by a `.`.  We have to escape the `.` (`\\.`), otherwise it will be considered as any single character.

I am not changing anything except in the `starts_with` part.  In the `mutate_each` if we need to pass a function, it can be passed inside a `funs` call.  In the above code, we are multiplying each of the columns (`.`) selected by the `matches` with the 'Freq' column.

According to `?select`

> ‘matches(x, ignore.case = TRUE)’: selects all variables whose
>             name matches the regular expression ‘x’

EDIT: Added @docendodiscimus comment's

Comment: You might want to use `matches("^[A-Z]\\.", ignore.case = FALSE)` since it defaults to TRUE and OP wants to matach capital letters. Compare for example `select(iris, matches("^[a-z].*"))` and `select(iris, matches("^[a-z].*", ignore.case = FALSE))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks, didn't check the default case.

Answer (score 3):

I just answered [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44034791/4249750) from other user, `mutate_each` will be deprecated in favor of `mutate_at`.

In your case the equivalent code is:

`df %>% mutate_at(.cols=vars(matches("^[A-Z]\\.", ignore.case=FALSE)), .funs=funs(.*Freq))`

`ID Freq L.abc L.ABC T.xyz F.ABC
1  1  0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.4
2  2  0.2   0.2   0.6   0.2   1.0
3  3  0.3   0.3   0.6   0.3   1.8
4  4  0.5   1.5   2.0   0.5   2.5
5  5  0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.3
6  6  0.3   0.0   0.3   0.3   0.3`