# Forcing mutate_each to create new column names for a subset of columns evaluate via ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, dplyr

## Problem

I'm working with a data frame similar to the extract generated below:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(columnA1 = 1:10,
                 columnB1 = 1:10,
                 columnB99 = runif(n = 10))
```

*I would like to create a set of columns that would contain custom flags corresponding to the values derived from columns that have **1** in the column name.*

## Approach

My present approach is summarised below:

```
require(dplyr); require(magrittr)
df %<>%
    mutate_each(funs(ifelse(. == 1, "val1",
                            ifelse(. == 10, "val10", NA))),
                contains("1"))
```

this generates the required values, however, does not create additional columns:

```
> head(df, n = 10)
   columnA1 columnB1  columnB99
1      val1     val1 0.26550866
2      <NA>     <NA> 0.37212390
3      <NA>     <NA> 0.57285336
4      <NA>     <NA> 0.90820779
5      <NA>     <NA> 0.20168193
6      <NA>     <NA> 0.89838968
7      <NA>     <NA> 0.94467527
8      <NA>     <NA> 0.66079779
9      <NA>     <NA> 0.62911404
10    val10    val10 0.06178627
```

### Comments / Attempt 1

```
I also tried:
df %<>%
    mutate_each(funs(flg = ifelse(. == 1, "val1",
                            ifelse(. == 10, "val10", NA))),
                contains("1"))
```

but it generates the same result. Following [this discussion](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/712), I'm guessing that I'm making mistakes in providing the suffix within the `funs`.

---

## Comments Follow-up

For example the code:

```
df %<>%
    mutate_each(funs(ifelse(. == 1, "val1", NA),
                     ifelse(. == 10, "val10", NA)),
                contains("1"))
head(df, 10)
```

would create the additional columns but the results are not fully satisfactory:

```
> head(df, 10)
   columnA1 columnB1  columnB99 columnA1_ifelse columnB1_ifelse columnA1_ifelse_ifelse columnB1_ifelse_ifelse
1         1        1 0.26550866            <NA>            <NA>                     NA                     NA
2         2        2 0.37212390            <NA>            <NA>                     NA                     NA
3         3        3 0.57285336            <NA>            <NA>                     NA                     NA
4         4        4 0.90820779            <NA>            <NA>                     NA                     NA
5         5        5 0.20168193            <NA>            <NA>                     NA                     NA
6         6        6 0.89838968            <NA>            <NA>                     NA                     NA
7         7        7 0.94467527            <NA>            <NA>                     NA                     NA
8         8        8 0.66079779            <NA>            <NA>                     NA                     NA
9         9        9 0.62911404            <NA>            <NA>                     NA                     NA
10       10       10 0.06178627           val10           val10                     NA                     NA
```

Comment: @akrun I was thinking that it would be possible to deviate from the default behaviour by providing that suffix.

Comment: I tried your edited code on the original dataset 'df'.  It didn't create the additional columns.  I am using `dplyr_0.4.3`

Comment: @akrun I honestly don't know why. I tried one more time and it runs ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jQsGg0bM)). I'm also using `0.4.3` version of `dplyr`.

Comment: Probably, it is the second run created that.  I don't know if that is a bug, but certainly, the NA columns are not the expected

Comment: @akrun Thanks, it's interesting why it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create additional columns when using only a single function in the `funs` argument if you supply a named vector to the `vars` or `...` argument within `mutate_each`. Here's an example using `setNames`:

```
mutate_each(df, funs(ifelse(. == 1, "val1",
                            ifelse(. == 10, "val10", NA))),
                setNames(contains("1"), c("x", "y")))
#   columnA1 columnB1  columnB99     x     y
#1         1        1 0.26550866  val1  val1
#2         2        2 0.37212390  <NA>  <NA>
#3         3        3 0.57285336  <NA>  <NA>
#4         4        4 0.90820779  <NA>  <NA>
#5         5        5 0.20168193  <NA>  <NA>
#6         6        6 0.89838968  <NA>  <NA>
#7         7        7 0.94467527  <NA>  <NA>
#8         8        8 0.66079779  <NA>  <NA>
#9         9        9 0.62911404  <NA>  <NA>
#10       10       10 0.06178627 val10 val10
```

This is also described in [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027347/).