# How to perform a separate() followed by a mutate_each() with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have data in an sqlite database that contains an entity that is not in first normal form. The strings in column 'sample_attribute'   look like this:

```
 isolate: R4166 || age: 43.88 || biomaterial_provider: LIBD || sex: male || tissue: DLPFC || disease: control || race: AA || RIN: 8.7 || Fraction: total || BioSampleModel: Human
```

My code at this time:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)



rs.df <- structure(list(run_accession = c("SRR1554537", "SRR2071348"), 
platform_parameters = c("INSTRUMENT_MODEL: Illumina HiSeq 2000", 
"INSTRUMENT_MODEL: Illumina HiSeq 2000"), sample_attribute = c("isolate: R3452 || age: -0.3836 || biomaterial_provider: LIBD || sex: female || tissue: DLPFC || disease: control || race: AA || RIN: 9.6 || Fraction: total || BioSampleModel: Human", "isolate: R3452 || age: -0.3836 || biomaterial_provider: LIBD || sex: female || tissue: DLPFC || disease: control || race: AA || RIN: 9.6 || Fraction: total || BioSampleModel: Human")), .Names = c("run_accession", "platform_parameters", "sample_attribute"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

coln <- c("isolate", "age", "biomaterial_provider", "sex", "tissue", "disease", "race",
          "RIN", "Fraction", "BioSampleModel")

rs.df <- rs.df %>%
        separate(sample_attribute, coln, sep = "\\|\\|")

head(rs.df, 1)
```

Intermediate Result:

```
       sample_attribute
  run_accession                   platform_parameters         isolate          age
1    SRR1554534 INSTRUMENT_MODEL: Illumina HiSeq 2000 isolate: DLPFC   age: 40.42 
          biomaterial_provider         sex          tissue            disease
1  biomaterial_provider: LIBD   sex: male   tissue: DLPFC   disease: Control 
        race        RIN          Fraction         BioSampleModel
1  race: AA   RIN: 8.4   Fraction: total   BioSampleModel: Human
```

Currently I continue with

```
for (x in coln){
        rs.df[,x] <- stri_replace(rs.df[,x], regex = "^.+:\\s*", replacement = "")
}
```

but that's inflexible.

**Is there a way to extend the dplyr pipeline such that  the for-loop is being replaced  (as far as possible) with calls in the %>% pipeline?**

At least, for values of the columns in `coln`, remove the strings until the colon from the result of the `separate()` call :

```
rs.df <- rs.df %>%
        separate(sample_attribute, coln, sep = "\\|\\|") %>%
        mutate_each(... stri_replace...) #split pairs at ":", remove part before ":"
```

(Here the for-loop has solved my problem of separating/cleaning up the strings. However, there are probably more such columns in the SRAdb database with key:valuepairs separated by "||". How to process them in a more flexible way?)

Comment: hi, can u share some rs data? dput(head(rs,100))

Comment: Can you please boil down your question to the essential problem and leave the rest of the code out?

Comment: added `structure()` and removed some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the answer by @docendo discimus here: [dplyr certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027347/mutate-each-summarise-each-in-dplyr-how-do-i-select-certain-columns-and-give)

in your case

```
rs.df <- rs.df %>%
    separate(sample_attribute, coln, sep = "\\|\\|") %>%
    mutate_each_(funs(stri_replace(., regex="^.+:\\s*", replacement="")), coln)
```

Comment: thanks, didn't know that there is a `mutate_each_()` with trailing underscore. Yesterday I tried it with a `mutate_each()` and it didn't work and I began doubting everything.