# Divide the values in one column by those in another column in R

Tags: r

I have read how to divide the values in one column by those in another column in R. But I want to know how to divide the values in multiple columns by the values in a single column. Also my first column is composed of non-numerics. How do a write a script in R to do all this and avoid the non-numeric?

I want to divide `HDL` and `HDW` by `SVL` in the .csv doc below

```
species SVL      HDL    HDW
PM     26.68    9.27    9.83
PM     23.46    8.41    8.59
PM     24.15    8.36    8.1
PM     23.09    8.91    8.79
Tioman 31.8    11.65    11.18
Tioman 29      10.88    10.66
```

Comment: In "species SVL HDL HDW PM 26.68 9.27 9.83 PM 23.46 8.41 8.59 PM 24.15 8.36 8.1 PM 23.09 8.91 8.79 Tioman 31.8 11.65 11.18 Tioman 29 10.88 10.66", there are no even line breaks

Comment: `df1[c("HDW", "HDL")] / df1$SVL`

Comment: @user2957945 though yours is fine, is it more common to reference them by column-index instead of list-index? `dat[,c("HDL","HDW")] / dat[,"SVL"]`

Comment: @r2evans; Im not sure it makes a difference  - less typing without the comma.

Comment: I think it's mostly stylistic, but the column-based (`df1[,"SVL"]`) is required to get a `numeric` vector on the denom, required to divide all numer columns by a single vector (as you demonstrate in your suggestion ... beating me by seconds :-).

Comment: Both of these worked very well. But when I print them to a .csv doc. how do I get column 1 (the non-numeric) to print with the ratios? That way I can keep track of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I like the dplyr package for this stuff. Given you have read in your data as a csv, then it is easy to define new columns as functions of other ones using the `mutate` command.
e.g.

```
require(dplyr)
mydata<-tbl_df(mydata) #Make it into a tbl class
#Define the new columns
mydata<-mydata%>%
  mutate(HDLSVL=HDL/SVL)%>%
  mutate(HDWSVL=HDW/SVL)
```

Comment: `?mutate_all` might make this a bit simpler.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't come across `mutate_all` yet. Looks like I need to update my version of dplyr :)

Comment: Also, no need for two `mutate()` calls. Can just be `mydata%>%mutate(HDLSVL=HDL/SVL, HDWSVL=HDW/SVL)`

Comment: Ah - I didn't realise that. I'm still a little green when it comes to dplyr.

Comment: @pablo_sci. You got it the wrong way: `mutate_each()` is deprecated.
Use `mutate_all()`, `mutate_at()` or `mutate_if()` instead.

Comment: Yeap Gabra, that answer was not updated. The correct one is at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44034791/4249750. It explains how to use mutate_at in the different versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through it (`lapply(..`) and divide (`/`) with the 'SVL'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, `/`, df1$SVL), .SDcols = HDL:HDW]
```

If we need to create new columns based on the divided output, then

```
setDT(df1)[, paste0(names(df1)[3:4],"_SVL") := lapply(.SD, `/`, df1$SVL), .SDcols = HDL:HDW]
```

Comment: @akrunhow do you recommend passing more than one column to the `[, lapply(.SD, `/`, df1$SVL)` argument?. In my df with 48 columns, I tried passing column names like so: `setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, `/`, df1$col25:df1$col48), .SDcols = col1:col24]`. In this instance, `col25` was used as the numerator for each successive operation applied to `col1`:`col24` variables instead of `col1`/`col25`, `col2`/`col26`...`col24`/`col48`. The errors produced were: `numerical expression has 3532 elements: only the first used` & `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`.

Comment: @akrun how do we deal with this assuming the column names are unknown?

Comment: @akrun how do we deal with this assuming the column names are unknown?

Comment: @NelsonGon  In that case, if you have the column index, use that

Comment: @akrun I asked my question that someone unfortunately chose to vote for closure. Anyways, I cannot know the column index because it's a function that takes on any data. I'll try to see if I can accomplish it. Thanks!

Comment: @NelsonGon  If there is no column index or column names, it is not clear what you want to accomplish.  Is it stored in an object?

Comment: I've resolved to do it outside the function. Thanks for your help.